# How to create a custom SharePoint webpart that connects to another webpart?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to create a custom webpart that can connect to the Query String (URL) Filter and use the values in my webpart.

How can I do this? Is there a JSOM function for this? How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Out of the box webpart - **Query string filter web part** to achieve this. 
You can also user this web part to filter data in connected webparts. This webpart works behind the scenes (is not visible to the user). There is an excellent article [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Query-String-URL-Filter-Web-Part-to-another-Web-Part-8FD0107F-4889-451B-A7F7-D1996E12A8D1) that explains the usage of this webpart and how can this webpart be connected with other weparts.